# Número máximo de un resultado while

Tags: php

Tenga el siguiente código:

```php
<?php 
while($consultax = mysql_fetch_array($consul)){
    echo "".$contador.","; //me arroja el siguiente valor 20,21,1
}
echo $contador; //Me arroja el siguiente valor 1
?>
```

Lo que necesito mostrar el número máximo del resultado del `while` fuera del `while`. En este caso, es el número `21`, pero me muestra el último número, que en este caso es el `1`. ¿Cómo lo ordeno? o ¿Cómo puedo hacer que muestre solo el número máximo fuera del `while`?

Actualizo:

Quise poner la explicación lo mas breve posible, para no complicar mucho pero la formulación completa, que es esta:

Lo que busco con el código es traer la cantidad de días laborados, yo tengo cantidad *X* de cédulas, y debo de traer el número máximo de días laborados, según el registro de la base de datos análisis.

```php
$calculosup = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM analisis_supervisor 
WHERE supervisor = '".$minfrax['cedula']."' AND grupo = ".$gruposuper."
") or die(mysql_error());

while($calculosupx = mysql_fetch_array($calculosup))
{
    //CANTIDAD DE MOVILES GENERAL
    $analisis_instalacionesMOV = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT fecha FROM analisis as ana
    left join admin_carpetas as ac on ana.tipo=ac.tipo
    WHERE ana.fecha LIKE '%".$mesfec."%'
        AND ana.movil = ".$calculosupx['movil']."
        AND (ac.grupo LIKE '%instalacion%')
        AND ana.tipo NOT LIKE '%PYME%'
        GROUP BY fecha") or die(mysql_error());
    $contador=0;
    $moviles;
    while($analisis_instalacionesMOVx = mysql_fetch_array($analisis_instalacionesMOV)){
        $analisis_instalacionesMOV2 = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT movil FROM analisis as ana
        left join admin_carpetas as ac on ana.tipo=ac.tipo
        WHERE ana.fecha LIKE '%".$analisis_instalacionesMOVx['fecha']."%'
            AND ana.movil = ".$calculosupx['movil']."
            AND (ac.grupo LIKE '%instalacion%')
            AND ana.resultado LIKE '%OK%'
            AND ana.tipo NOT LIKE '%PYME%'") or die(mysql_error());
            $analisis_instalacionesMOV2n = mysql_num_rows($analisis_instalacionesMOV2);
            $moviles +=$analisis_instalacionesMOV2n;
            $contador++;
    }
    echo "".$contador.","; //me arroja el siguiente valor 20,21,1
}
echo $contador; //Me arroja el siguiente valor 1
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el contenido de `$consultax` para cada iteración del bucle? ¿Que recupera de la consulta? Además, ¿Por qué muestras el valor de `$contador` si lo que quieres es mostrar los resultados de `$consultax`?

Comment: Seria mas facil que en tu consulta hagas un query obteniendo el numeto maximo que necesitas

Comment: Como dice @MiguelOsorio En la Query sería mas fácil, si te quieres complicar... Guardaría la consulta en un array y de ahí evaluaría el mismo array.

Comment: Ahora mismo con tu nuevo edit la variable `$contador` no devolverá nada ya que no le estás asignando ningún valor.

Comment: En la SQL lo que haría sería `SELECT algo FROM tabla ORDER BY loquequieres ASC LIMIT 0,1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que podrías realizar sería guardar el número máximo anterior que ha aparecido y compararlo con el nuevo número. Si es mayor que el número máximo anterior, entonces sobreescribir el número máximo anterior por el nuevo.

En tu código sería:

```
$maximoValor = 0;
while($calculosupx = mysql_fetch_array($calculosup))
{
    //Tu código
    while($analisis_instalacionesMOVx = mysql_fetch_array($analisis_instalacionesMOV)){
         //Tu código
         $contador++;
    }
    echo "".$contador.","; //me arroja el siguiente valor 20,21,1
    //Comparas si el número actual es mayor que el número máximo que ha salido hasta el momento
    if ($contador > $maximoValor){ 
        $maximoValor = $contador; //Si es así, sobreescribes el valor de $maximoValor
    }
}
echo $maximoValor; //Te devolverá 21
```